# Javamail: BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

For a certain ISP, I have been running into this exception for every message:

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A33 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:353)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.fetchRFC822(IMAPProtocol.java:1378)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getHeader(IMAPMessage.java:772)
```

Upon inspection it seems to happen when the program tries to get the `Message-ID` header like this:

```
message.getHeader("Message-ID")
```

But for some reason if I do this before getting the header(s) by name:

```
Enumeration<?> headers = m.getAllHeaders();

while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    Header header = (Header) headers.nextElement();
}
```

The exceptions go away.

Also, here's the list of headers I am getting:

```
[Return-Path, Received, Received, **Message-Id**, X-CT-Class, X-CT-Score, X-CT-RefID, X-CT-Spam, X-Authority-Analysis, X-CM-Score, Return-Path, DKIM-Signature, Received, List-Unsubscribe, **Message-ID**, MIME-Version, Reply-To, Subject, From, To, Date, Content-Type]
```

Also here's the `debug` log:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.cox.net", port 993, isSSL true
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4 AUTH=PLAIN] Ready
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.cox.net, user=ym1abc, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A0 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS NAMESPACE QUOTA] LOGIN completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A1 SELECT INBOX
* 5439 EXISTS
* OK [UNSEEN 2] First unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1339789718] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 518252] Predicted next UID
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft \Seen)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\* \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft \Seen)] Permanent flags
* 0 RECENT
A1 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
2017-01-06 16:31:27,882 INFO  [main]         org.abc.del.ibx.main.Main     - 5439
A2 FETCH 1:20 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODYSTRUCTURE RFC822.SIZE RFC822.HEADER.LINES (X-PVIQ X-Campid X-Vitals X-PVIQ X-Originating-IP Received Message-ID Newsgroups Received-SPF X-Header-MasterId X-Header-CompanyDBUserName))
A2 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH
A3 FETCH 1 (RFC822.HEADER.LINES (Message-ID))
A3 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPProtocol noop
A4 NOOP
A4 OK NOOP completed
2017-01-06 16:31:28,854 ERROR [main] org.abc.del.ibx.utilities.Mutator     - Exception :> A3 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH
javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A3 BAD Invalid attribute list in FETCH
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getHeader(IMAPMessage.java:893)
    at org.abc.del.ibx.utilities.Mutator.parseMessage(Mutator.java:59)
    at org.abc.del.ibx.main.Main.processMessages(Main.java:147)
    at org.abc.del.ibx.main.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

In the list, I see that `Message-Id` header is duplicated.

So I have couple of questions:

1. What's causing the exception & what would be the better solution than to get all headers first? In my case, I need to get all headers one by one since we record it in DB.
2. Is duplicate header causing the issue?

Comment: Notice that the duplicate headers differ in case.  It looks like your server is broken; what server is this?  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) with show you exactly what it's doing.  Can you post the debug output showing the error?

Comment: @BillShannon I just updated my question with the debug log & the ISP in the question is Cox.net

Comment: The server is broken. It advertises the older "IMAP4" capability instead of the newer "IMAP4rev1" capability, but it's not accepting the older IMAP4 RFC822.HEADER.LINES fetch attribute, which is no longer part of IMAP4rev1.  It's hard to say whether it's just a very old IMAP4 server that only implemented a subset of the IMAP4 spec, or whether it's a new server that doesn't correctly advertise that it's really an IMAP4rev1 server.  My guess is the former, but either way you need to report this problem to Cox.

Comment: You can try [this workaround from the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug), or try using [IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.HEADERS](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.html#HEADERS) with the [Folder.fetch method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#fetch-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.FetchProfile-).  Any of these will avoid using the RFC822.HEADER.LINES attribute that the server is complaining about, but you may run into other problems with this broken server.

Comment: But why do the exceptions go away when I get all headers first?

Comment: Because it uses a different IMAP command that the server seems to support.  The headers are all then cached locally and the subsequent getHeader call uses the local cache instead of the RFC822.HEADER.LINES IMAP fetch attribute.